# Go to definition in visual studio code does not work with Package.json for components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm following the structure where I've src/components and I've created a pacakge.json file with code

```
{
  "name": "@components"
}
```

It works fine and I can import all the components with absolute path but it does not go to definition of the component on clicking. Any help will be much appreciated.

Note: I'm using vs code